# How to use pyparsing to parse and hash strings enclosed by special characters?

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, mediawiki, pyparsing

The majority of pyparsing examples that I have seen have dealt with linear expressions.

a = 1 + 2

I'd like to parse mediawiki headlines, and hash them to their sections.

e.g.

```
Introduction goes here
==Hello==
foo
foo
===World===
bar
bar
```

Dict would look like:

```
{'Introduction':'Whoot introduction goes here', 'Hello':"foo\nfoo", 'World':"bar\nbar"}
```

If I could just see one example of this "enclosed" (==HEADLINE==) parsing, I'd be able to move on to links/images/files etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you miss [this wiki-like language parser](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleWiki.py) in the pyParsing web site examples?

```
h2 = QuotedString("==")
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, this format is not unlike a .INI file:

```
[section1]
a = 1
b = 3
[section2]
blah=a
```

Which can be parsed into a nested dictionary using [this example code](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/configParse.py).